# Cannot edit items in DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid, mvvm-light

I've added a DataGrid to my main view, but now I'm encountering the problem I cannot edit the values, nor add new rows. Deleting rows works though, can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

EDIT: This projects is being created using the MVVM Light Toolkit

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="PartExplorer.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:ignore="http://www.ignore.com"
    mc:Ignorable="d ignore"
    Height="300"
    Width="300"
    Title="{Binding WelcomeTitle}"
    DataContext="{Binding Main, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">

    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Skins/MainSkin.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding PriceItems, Mode=TwoWay}" IsReadOnly="False" CanUserAddRows="True"  />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainViewModel.cs

```
...
    /// <summary>
    /// The <see cref="PriceItems" /> property's name.
    /// </summary>
    public const string PriceItemsPropertyName = "PriceItems";

    private ObservableCollection<PriceItem> _priceItems = new ObservableCollection<PriceItem>();

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets and gets the PriceBook property.
    /// Changes to that property's value raise the PropertyChanged event. 
    /// </summary>
    public ObservableCollection<PriceItem> PriceItems
    {
        get
        {
            return _priceItems;
        }

        set
        {
            if (_priceItems == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            RaisePropertyChanging(PriceItemsPropertyName);
            _priceItems = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(PriceItemsPropertyName);
        }
    }
...
```

PriceItem.cs

```
public class PriceItem
{
    public PriceItem()
    {
        Name = "";
        Price = 0;
        Weight = 0;
        PartType = Type.Standard;
    }

    public PriceItem(string name, double price, int weight, Type partType)
    {
        Name = name;
        Price = price;
        Weight = weight;
        PartType = partType;
    }

    public Type PartType { get; private set; }
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public double Price { get; private set; }
    public int Weight { get; private set; }
}

public enum Type
{
    Standard,
    Special
}
```

Comment: Copied your code 1:1, works for me...

Comment: @amnezjak: So when you run the code you can edit the values in the datagrid? That's very strange, since I cannot.. I'm reffering to editing the values at runtime if that was not clear..

Comment: try to use 

UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged

in the items source of the Grid im never goin without it :D

Comment: @dennisschütz I tried adding this, but sadly doesn't make any difference

Comment: @Tom yes I can. And what do you mean by "cannot edit" - the in-place editor doesn't show up or edited value doesn't propagate to the underlying data source? Also, the there may be a problem in DataContext, I set mine in code-behind.

Comment: @amnezjak The grid shows up, but when I try to click on a value there's no editor or nothing showing up. Also, I don't know how to set my datacontext in the code since I'm new to the whole mvvm experience, and I can't refer to my datagrid from my viewmodel (afaik)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I'm stupid. 
Make setters in your `PriceItem` class public.

Comment: Lol, no I'm stupid XD I can't believe I've been looking for this for over an hour.. Thank you for this, a lot! :P